# How to convert a column or sequence of Vectors to a SparseMatrix?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, matrix, sparse-matrix

As the title says, I have a sequence of vectors (in a DataFrame column, but this can be converted to an RDD or to a sequence using .collect() ). I want to collect these vectors into a local SparseMatrix. For back-compatibility with Spark 1.6.3, I need this to be the mllib version of [SparseMatrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseMatrix).

Collected as a sequence of SparseVectors, I get

```
val seq_of_vectors = df_with_vectors.select("sparse").map(_.getAs[SparseVector](0)).collect()
seq_of_vectors: Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector] = ...
```

I can make a RowMatrix easily, but I don't see any way to convert a RowMatrix to a local matrix either.

```
val exampleMatrix = new RowMatrix(df_with_vectors.select("sparse").rdd.map(_.getAs[SparseVector](0)))
exampleMatrix: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix = org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix@2e6273dc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a sequence of SparseVector objects in the form

```
seq_of_vectors: Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector] = 
    Array(..., (262144,[136034,155107,166596],[0.8164965809277259,0.40824829046386296,0.40824829046386296]), ...
```

We convert to a coordinate list tuple of (rows, column, value) using:

```
val coo = (seq_of_vectors.map(_.numNonzeros).zipWithIndex.flatMap{case (cnt, idx) => Array.fill(cnt)(idx) },
    seq_of_vectors.map(_.indices).flatten,
    seq_of_vectors.map(_.values).flatten
).zipped.toArray

coo: Array[(Int, Int, Double)] = 
    Array( ..., (28,136034,0.8164965809277259), (28,155107,0.40824829046386296), (28,166596,0.40824829046386296), ...
```

Then we use the `fromCOO` function of `SparseMatrix`. The number of rows is the number of vectors passed; while the number of columns is the length of the longest SparseVector:

```
SparseMatrix.fromCOO(seq_of_vectors.length,
    seq_of_vectors.map(_.size).max,
    coo)

res223: org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.SparseMatrix = 
84 x 262144 CSCMatrix
...
(28,136034) 0.8164965809277259
...
(28,155107) 0.40824829046386296
...
(28,166596) 0.40824829046386296
...
```